# mysqldb using execute() method to execute multi SQL queries

Tags: mysql-python

```python
sql = 'use datacheck;select * from users'

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(sql)

res_set = cursor.fetchall()
```

In this way, the `res_set = ()`, but when execute this SQL directly in databases, it returns all the results.

If I change the SQL to `select * from users`, it returns the corrected result.

I just want to know why, is there any documents describing the `execute()` method?

Answer (score 0):

In your statement, there are two instructions

```
use datacheck;
```

then

```
select * from users;
```

And the first one is executedonly the first is executed, that's why you have no result with your query.
[execute documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)